# Can we authorize user to own API through another application and Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api

It will be rather hard question because I don't know how it should be correctly ask. First of all some background.

I have got application written in ruby on rails lets name it ruby_app and it provides some basic authentication API.
Someone else needs mobile application name it mobile_app (separate client) that use ruby_app through provided API.
Single sign in and registration process through Facebook allows user to edit some hidden part of ruby_app also regular sign_in and registration do it. 
In ruby_app currently we can sign_up and sign_in through Facebook.

**But I don't have any idea how to allow sign_in with mobile_app using Facebook through my API.
Can it be achieved?**

If yes some explanation would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sign in to use an API.

The most simple solution is to assign a user a random string (api key).

- mobile_app should send the api_key with every API request
- ruby_app should check that the sent API request is valid
- optionally, mobile_app should be able to retrieve the API key automatically by sending a username/password.

Comment: I should rest. You have got right. I was just wondering if facebook_application is able to post to ruby_app with provided by facebook_user data. It caused that I missed my point with this question